# writing an xml file that contains a euro symbol (€) in Python using xml.etree

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree, euro

I am trying to use xml.etree to read and write xml files containing a € symbol.

My simplified code looks like this:

```
optionsdirectory = os.getcwd()
optionsfile = os.path.join(optionsdirectory, "conf")
optionstree = ET.parse(optionsfile)
options = optionstree.getroot()
for option in options:
    if option.tag == "currency":
        option.text = "€"
optionstree.write(optionsfile, encoding="UTF-8")
```

I get the following error when it is run:

```
File "C:\curr.py", line 8
    optionstree.write(optionsfile, encoding="UTF-8")
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 815, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 934, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 932, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1068, in _escape_cdata
    return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 2114: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to write a € symbol to an xml file using xml.etree?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a unicode literal. It'll be easier to use a unicode escape instead of the character:

```
option.text = u"\u20AC"  # Euro sign
```

What happens when you do not use a unicode literal but a byte (string) literal instead, is that Python tries to decode the value to a unicode literal using the default encoding, which is ASCII. This results in the UnicodeDecodeError you saw.

If you really *do* want to use the unescaped character, make sure you specify the encoding of your source file at the top:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and make sure your editor uses UTF-8 to save the file. You'd still have to use a unicode literal though:

```
option.text = u"€"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to creating an XML file with non-ASCII characters.  Note that you need to save the source file in the encoding declared via `# coding:` and use Unicode literals (`u'string'`).  In the example below I write the file as both UTF-8 and ASCII to demonstrate that ElementTree will read the file correctly in either case:

```
# coding: utf8
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

# Create the root element.
root = et.Element('test')
root.text = u'123€456'

# Wrap the root in an ElementTree and write files.
tree = et.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('utf8.xml',encoding='UTF-8')
tree.write('ascii.xml',encoding='ascii')

# Verify that each file can be read correctly.
tree = et.parse('utf8.xml')
print tree.getroot().text
tree = et.parse('ascii.xml')
print tree.getroot().text

# display the raw contents of the files
with open('utf8.xml','rb') as f:
    print repr(f.read())
with open('ascii.xml','rb') as f:
    print repr(f.read())
```

Note the output.  0xE2 0x82 0xAC is the UTF-8 hexadecimal sequence for the euro character.  `&#8364;` is the character reference.

```
123€456
123€456
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<test>123\xe2\x82\xac456</test>"
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ascii'?>\n<test>123&#8364;456</test>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was good with web pages but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to "respond" to a post on this site as others have. So I need to create this new answer ...

Thanks for your response Mark Tolonen. Both your response and Martijn Pieters' response involved using Unicode literals. However that will not work for me. The XML file I am working with will be created by writing out file names which contain a € symbol. I get the file names through the following code:

```
for file in os.listdir(r'C:\test'):
    filenamelist = filenamelist + " " + file
```

Some of these file names will contain the € symbol in the file name itself. I then want to write these file names as an XML attribute as follows:

```
optionsdirectory = os.getcwd()
optionsfile = os.path.join(optionsdirectory, "conf.xml")
optionstree = ET.parse(optionsfile)
options = optionstree.getroot()
for option in options:
    if option.tag == "filenames":
        option.text = filenamelist
optionstree.write(optionsfile, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Initially I will have an xml file, 'conf.xml', which will contain an empty 'filenames' attribute. I know it's kludgy but it works for my purposes.

So, the € symbol cannot come from a Unicode literal. When I run the above code I get the error I posted in my original post, which basically says when it encounters the € symbol in 'filenamelist' it throws up its hands.

Comment: Well I finally figured it out. I did the following three things. I think each of them are required:   1) Save the initial 'conf.xml' file as a UTF-8 file (this enables the ET.parse() to work)   2) change 'filenamelist = filenamelist + " " + file' to 'filenamelist = filenamelist + " " + file.decode('ISO-8859-1')' (this makes the file name text suitable for writing)   3) change the write() statement to 'optionstree.write(optionsfile, encoding='ISO-8859-1')' (to match the encoding used for the filenames)

Comment: I should also note that I am using Python version 2.7. I read they changed things wrt unicode processing in version 3.x; perhaps I would not have had these problems with Python 3.x